# BigQuery: get table description using INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Tags: google-bigquery, information-schema

Is it possible go get a BigQuery table's description from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS` view with `option_name = 'desciption'`

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_crime`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS
 WHERE option_name = 'description'
   AND table_name = 'crime';
```

**Query results**

[image]

- `option_value` shows a table description.
- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-table-options